# Check whether string exists in a string, no matter if uppercase/lowercase/mixed?

Tags: python, string

I want to check, if a string exists in another string, but when I search for the string, I can only get a confirmation, when the string is exactly the same. How can I bypass that?

Comment: Convert both strings to the same case before checking if it exists.

Comment: `string.lower()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it checks whether string is contained in string2 (case insensitive) after verifying they are different :

```
string != string2 and str.lower(string) in str.lower(string2)
```